# WordPress Facebook Comment Count in archive

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I want to display the Facebook comment count on my blog archives.

My wordpress site has the following php function in **function.php**

```
    // Get combined FB and WordPress comment count
    function full_comment_count() {
    global $post;
    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

    $filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
    $json = json_decode($filecontent);
    $count = $json->$url->comments;
    $wpCount = get_comments_number();
    $realCount = $count + $wpCount;
    if ($realCount == 0 || !isset($realCount)) {
        $realCount = 0;
    }
    return $realCount;
    }
```

This is how I am using the function on a template file inside a loop `<?php echo full_comment_count(); ?>`

Most of the time most of the articles show "0" comments. But sometime one or 2 of them work. what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function full_comment_count() {
global $post;
$url = get_permalink($post->ID);

$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$count = $json->$url->comments;
if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
}
echo $count;
}
```

Comment: The count for all is set at 0... The site I am using it on is www.womenoffaith.com in the blog archive... any theories?

Comment: Refer http://screencast.com/t/NEfpNJ06rl72. All the comments count is displaying fine. Share the URL where exactly you are facing the issue.